# Importing an existing movement data in a Netlogo network simulation

Tags: netlogo

In my ABM model, I generate a network where agents (walkers breed) move from one node to another linked node. In my current code below derived from the examples in Netlogo, the walkers can only move randomly to another linked node.

My question is, how can import existing movement data of an agent (walker) including the time element (since the data has a time stamp when a certain agent reached a node)?

My current code:

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]
breed [wildlifes wildlife]

undirected-link-breed [paths path]
undirected-link-breed [wlpaths wlpath]

walkers-own [
  location
  list-locations
  carrier?
  nb-carrier
]  ;; holds a node

nodes-own [
  infected?
  nb-infected-node
]

wildlifes-own [
  infectious?
]

turtles-own [node-id]

paths-own [strength]

globals [
  paths-list
]

to import-network
  clear-all
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  import-attributes
  layout-circle (sort nodes) (max-pxcor - 1)
  import-paths
  reset-ticks
end

;; This procedure reads in a files that contains node-specific attributes
;; including an unique identification number
to import-attributes
  ;; This opens the file, so we can use it.
  file-open "attributes.txt"
  ;; Read in all the data in the file
  ;; data on the line is in this order:
  ;; node-id attribute1 attribute2
  while [not file-at-end?]
  [
    ;; this reads a single line into a three-item list
    let items read-from-string (word "[" file-read-line "]")
    create-nodes 1 [
      set node-id item 0 items
      set size    item 1 items
      ;set color   item 2 items
      set color blue
    ]
  ]
  file-close
end

;; This procedure reads in a file that contains all the links
;; The file is simply 3 columns separated by spaces.  In this
;; example, the links are directed.  The first column contains
;; the node-id of the node originating the link.  The second
;; column the node-id of the node on the other end of the link.
;; The third column is the strength of the link.

to import-paths
  ;; This opens the file, so we can use it.
  file-open "links.txt"
  ;; Read in all the data in the file
  while [not file-at-end?]
  [
    ;; this reads a single line into a three-item list
    let items read-from-string (word "[" file-read-line "]")
    ask get-node (item 0 items)
    [
      ;;create-link-to get-node (item 1 items) ;; creates a directed link
      create-path-with get-node (item 1 items) ;; creates an undirectec link
        [ set label item 2 items ]
    ]
  ]
  file-close
end

;; Helper procedure for looking up a node by node-id.
to-report get-node [id]
  report one-of nodes with [node-id = id]
end

to setup
  clear-all
  import-network
  wildlife-nodes
  ask nodes [ set infected? false ]
  ;; initial infected node
  ;ask one-of nodes [ 
  ;  set infected? true 
  ;  set color red
  ;  set nb-infected-node 0
  ;  set nb-infected-node nb-infected-node + 1
  ;]
  create-walkers 5 [
    set shape "arrow"
    set color yellow
    set carrier? false
    set nb-carrier 0
    ;;set location one-of nodes ;; walker goes to a random node
    set location one-of nodes with [ node-id = 1 ]
    set list-locations (list location)
    move-to location
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if all? nodes [ infected? ] [ stop ]
  ask paths [ set thickness 0 ]
  ask nodes [
    infect-walker
  ]
  ask walkers [
    transmit-disease
    let new-location one-of [ path-neighbors ] of location
    ;; change the thickness of the link I just crossed over
    ask [path-with new-location] of location [ set thickness 0.5 ]
    face new-location  ;; not strictly necessary, but improves the visuals a bit
    move-to new-location
    set location new-location
    set list-locations fput location list-locations
  ]
  ask wildlifes [
    infect-node
  ]
  tick
end

to infect-walker
  let walker-on-node one-of walkers-here
  if infected? and walker-on-node != nobody and transmission-rate < random 100 [
      ask one-of walkers-here [ 
        set carrier? true 
        set color violet
        set nb-carrier nb-carrier + 1
      ]
    ]
end

to transmit-disease
  ifelse carrier? and biosec-compliance-rate < random 100 [
    ask nodes-here [ 
      set infected? true 
      set color red
      set nb-infected-node nb-infected-node + 1
    ]
  ]
  [
    set carrier? false
  ]
end

to wildlife-nodes
  create-wildlifes 1 [
    setxy min-pxcor max-pycor
    set color green
    set shape "tree"
    set size 2
    set infectious? false
    create-wlpaths-with n-of 2 nodes
  ]
end

to infect-node
  if trans-rate-from-wildlife > random 100 [
    ask one-of wlpath-neighbors [
      set infected? true
    ]
  ]
end
```

I have not tried anything yet, but the data will likely include the unique agent ID, and the node it is in at a specific time. Basically, I will be simulating the movement of animals with beacons on them in a certain area where there are installed proximity sensors that detects the location of the beacons/animals. In the simulation, the devices are the stationary nodes, the links are present if a sensor can be reached from another sensor, and the animals/beacons are the moving agents.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data in a text file in CSV format, you can use the CSV extension to read the data into a NetLogo list.

Another useful format for the data would be in the form of a native NetLogo literal list, which NetLogo could read with a single read-from-file command.

The list would be a list of lists. Each row of the data would itself be a list of values.

You will make a reporter  procedure that reads the data, and reports the list of lists.

You might assign that to a global variable.

You will make a procedure that scans the list, quickly creating each unique walker turtle and each unique waypoint turtle, and linking the waypoints, as they are found in the data. Make sure to tag the walkers and waypoints with the ID values in the data.

If important, and present, you can use geospatial information in your data to position the waypoints, or let it be abstract and just use layout-spring in the usual way to let the graph self-organize. It may be enough to identity the top-left most, bottom-right-most and center-most waypoints, and pin them to the world, letting layout-spring do the rest (that is, you repeatedly set the position of the pinned nodes and use layout spring, creating a graph that is stretched between the fixed nodes)

If links have distance information, you can write your own version of layout-spring that uses that to inform the self-organization.

You may wish to make a simple mouse interface so you can manually untangle the graph, if needed.

Once you've got a version of the graph that is suitable, you may wish to save that as a file, either with export-world, or a homemade procedure to save the network data.

All that done, you can then write your go procedure to iterate the data, moving your walkers along the graph according to the time stamps.

You can use linear interpolation to slide the walkers along the links during the timespan between node arrivals, or have them pop from place to place, as best suits your purposes.

Make sure each walker has additional variables to assist with traversal, like current node, next node, next departure, next arrival, travel-time, travel-distance, so you can easily and clearly refer to those values in the procedure that places or moves the walkers.